# GraphQL dataloaders on same field names of different objects

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

consider following 2 GraphQL TypeObjects.

```
type Student {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    city: String
    pin : String
    phoneModel: String
}

Assume that we have a dataloader registered on phoneModel. Because phoneModel information is fetched from a different datasource. So, to avoid N + 1 issue, for each student record (id), we batch phoneModel request and finally send out one single query to get phoneModels.

type Employee {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    city: String
    pin : String
    phoneModel: String
}
Assume that phoneModel database here is completely different from above Student's Phone database. 

And phoneModel information is fetched from a different remote database.

I want to register dataloader on 'phoneModel' here too.
```

Problem:
dataloader.register(String Key, DataLoader BatchLoader);

For student object, it is registered as:

```
dataloader.register("phoneModel", StudentPhoneBatchLoader);
```

For Employee object, how do I register a dataloader without overwriting Student's dataloader.

```
dataloader.register("phoneModel", EmployeePhoneBatchLoader);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the workaround is to register dataloaders with unique-keys.

dataloader.register("StudentPhoneModel", StudentPhoneBatchLoader);
dataloader.register("EmployeePhoneModel", EmployeePhoneBatchLoader);

And when resolving field, do:
dataloader.getDataLoader("StudentPhoneModel") and
dataloader.getDataLoader("EmployeePhoneModel")